Varios puertos SSL para varios dominios en NGINX
Tengo dos proyectos alojados en un servidor VPS con ubuntu linux, ambos proyectos funcionan, pero tengo el problema de que solo se muestra el proyecto que lleva el puerto 443,y el proyecto que no lo tiene redirige al otro. Tengo habilitado el puerto 444 intentando que también tenga la misma función pero no lo acepta. Agradeceré cualquier sugerencia o corrección.
A continuación, proporciono el código de mi archivo 'sites-enabled/default'.
GNU nano 6.2                                       default                                                

# Configuración para el proyecto dominiouno
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name dominiouno.com www.dominiouno.com;

    location / {
        root /home/marco/dominiouno/build;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass https://000.000.36.100:8002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # Redirige a HTTPS
    listen [::]:444 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 444 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominiouno.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominiouno.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

# Configuración para el proyecto dominiodos
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name dominiodos.com www.dominiodos.com;

    location / {
        root /home/marco/dominiodos/build;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api-dominiodos {
        proxy_pass https://000.000.36.100:8003;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # Redirige a HTTPS
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominiodos.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominiodos.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}




habría que ver de que manera ingresas a cada dominio, ya que el doimnio 1 esta escuchando el puerto 444, habría que ver si ese puerto está abierto y para ingresar deberían usar https://dominiouno.com:444.
se podría arreglar un poco la redirección http>http
'# Redirige HTTP a HTTPS para dominiouno.com
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name dominiouno.com www.dominiouno.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Redirige HTTP a HTTPS para dominiodos.com
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name dominiodos.com www.dominiodos.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}'

Esta línea no creo que sea necesaria
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;

Esto está bien si deseas que solo las conexiones IPv6 utilicen esos puertos específicos.
Esta en una configuración mas estable
# Redirige HTTP a HTTPS para dominiouno.com
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dominiouno.com www.dominiouno.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Configuración para el proyecto dominiouno
server {
    listen 444 ssl;
    server_name dominiouno.com www.dominiouno.com;

    location / {
        root /home/marco/dominiouno/build;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass https://000.000.36.100:8002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
 
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominiouno.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominiouno.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

# Redirige HTTP a HTTPS para dominiodos.com
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dominiodos.com www.dominiodos.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Configuración para el proyecto dominiodos
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name dominiodos.com www.dominiodos.com;

    location / {
        root /home/marco/dominiodos/build;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api-dominiodos {
        proxy_pass https://000.000.36.100:8003;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominiodos.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominiodos.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

De todos modo ve la posibilidad de eliminar el puerto 444 ya que estas usando 2 dominios distintos y los estas redirigiendo, podes usar el puerto por default 443
Saludos.-
